# Attacking a update mechanism using MD5 and RSA

Tags: rsa, md5

I am currently working on a software challenge where you have to unlock several functions of a piece of software. The software is written in Java. One of them is the update mechanism of the firmware. What it does is to download a file from a webserver and make a few checks, before the update is performed. I need to find a way to overcome these checks in such a way, that I am able to update the firmware using my own created firmware update.

Here is how the update mechanism works:

1. The software downloads a file from the webserver. It is a zip file which should have the following structure:

   ```
   |Zip file content| SecurityTag: | Tag|
   ```

   - Zip file content: This is where I have to add a file, called `version.txt` which needs to contain a number `x > 1.0`. (The software reads that part as `ZipInputStream`.)
   - SecurityTag: This is a string, which has to be within this file! I cannot modify that one.
   - Tag: The Tag which is used during the check.
2. It takes the Zip file content, checks if the `version.txt` file is included and extracts the number from it.
3. It hashes the Zip file content using `hash = MD5(Zip file content)`
4. Takes the tag and decrypts it using RSA: `t = (tag)^e mod N`. I know `e` and `N`.
5. It verifies if `hash == t`

Somehow, I have to pass this check but I am not sure how. I started to look into different kind of attacks but none of it seemed like suitable in order to overcome that check.

Is there any attack scenario which I am missing here? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. What have you tried and why did it fail? Because from what you showed, it seems absolutely doable.

Comment: My problem is that I don't have any idea on how to do it. I am stuck at step 5, where I need to have a `tag`, which decrypted will result in the `hash`. I know the public key `e` but don't know the secret key `d`. I check signature forge attacks but I think that those do not help me here.

Comment: [cross posted](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/68727/29554) to crypto.stackexchange - it appears to be more on-topic for us then there, so I recommend closing the question on this site.